# How to show horizontal scrollbar on div contained in div with hidden scrollbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to show horizontal scrollbar on my "content" div if the screen size is smaller than the minimum width I've set for the div. The parent "container" overflow-x is set to hidden so the scroll won't show for the entire page.

```css
.content {
  background: cyan;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 1500px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="content">
        This is a test.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my current output below, the scrollbar is already visible but not scrollable. The div gets cut off as well. Which part needs to be changed to show scroll? I'm using Bootstrap 4.

[image]

Comment: Set property `overflow-y: scroll;`. And read Values from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Answer (score 4):

To enable `scroll-view`, you need to set `overflow-x: auto` on `.parent` div, not on `.content` div.

Keep `.content` div width to `1500px` and set x-scrollable on `.parent` div and it will work.

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.content {
  background: cyan;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 1500px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="content">
        This is a test.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While the scrollbar is now scrollable, the right side gets cut off when the screen is small.

Comment: I can't fill it on the current snippet. Can you attach the screenshot? @markuy

Comment: This is the output using the suggested code: https://i.imgur.com/RLZC8Ll.png

Comment: Add `display: inline-block;` on `.content` class and it will be filled. This problem happened because the text length is bigger than 1500px. @markuy

Answer (score 0):

Its working just fine as you did it. But when you change the width of your content div, the overflow gets cut of from the parent, only the content will activate the overflow.

```css
.content {
  background: cyan;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```